# Importing AVFoundation and using AudioQueueOutputCallback or AudioQueueInputCallback crashes source editor

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode7

I have a weird problem - it might be something in my code, but I don't think so. So if anyone has faced this before could shed some light, or can try to reproduce it on their machine and share the results, I'd appreciate it.

Xcode used: V. 7.3.

When using AudioQueue within AVFoundation, using AudioQueueOutputCallback or AudioQueueInputCallback repeatedly crashes the source editor with error "An internal error occurred. Source editor functionality is limited. Attempting to restore..." - to no avail. The Issue Navigator (as seen in the screenshot attached), displays "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11".

[image]

With the presence of "import AVFoundation" at the top of the file, using a snippet such as the one below, produces the problem I mentioned:

var outputCallback: AudioQueueOutputCallback = {
        (inUserData, outQA, outBuffer) in
        ...
}

Please do note using a similar pattern with other closures is just fine. The problem seems to be specific to AVFoundation and creating closures of type AudioQueueOutputCallback or AudioQueueInputCallback.

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Create a new project (or file).
2. import AVFoundation
3. Write the following snippet within the class:
var outputCallback: AudioQueueOutputCallback = {
        (inUserData, outQA, outBuffer) in
        return
}

Expected Results:
No error. Being able to use the closure handler "outputCallback".

Actual Results:
Xcode source editor crashes repeatedly with error "An internal error occurred. Source editor functionality is limited. Attempting to restore..." - to no avail. The Issue Navigator (as seen in the screenshot attached), displays "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11".

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Edit: Playground breakdown screenshot:
[image]

Edit 2: Adding details of bug Reported to Apple (never got a response)

When using AudioQueue within AVFoundation, using AudioQueueOutputCallback or AudioQueueInputCallback repeatedly crashes the source editor with error "An internal error occurred. Source editor functionality is limited. Attempting to restore..." - to no avail. The Issue Navigator (as seen in the screenshot attached), displays "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11".

With the presence of "import AVFoundation", using a snippet such as the following produces the aforementioned problem:

var outputCallback: AudioQueueOutputCallback = {
        (inUserData, outQA, outBuffer) in
        ...
}

Please do note using a similar pattern with other closures is just fine. The problem seems to be specific to AVFoundation and creating closures of type AudioQueueOutputCallback or AudioQueueInputCallback.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a new project (or file).
2. import AVFoundation
3. Write the following snippet within the class:

   var outputCallback: AudioQueueOutputCallback = {
           (inUserData, outQA, outBuffer) in
           return
   }

Comment: I just typed `var outputCallback: AudioQueueOutputCallback = { (inUserData, outQA, outBuffer) in print(inUserData) }` without having errors in Xcode 7.3 - I suggest you "Clean" the project and if necessary also "clean the derived data", probably this is just your Xcode freaking out.

Comment: @EricD thanks for the reply. I did clean (and hard-clean) as well as getting rid of derived data - the same. I did close Xcode as well as restart the whole Mac (I know - desperate measures but also desperate times!), the same.
The (un)funny thing is, even Playground temporarily breaks when I have the snippet I mentioned in it. I'll attach that to the question as well. I should mention, the Playground "attachment" error does go away, but it does break from time to time whilst the code is present... Weird.

Comment: Ok, so it means that there is *something else, elsewhere* that's causing this issue. Usually the culprit is some code from another class of yours or from a framework/sdk you're using in the project. The fact that your code works for me indicates that the problem does not come from the code or from Xcode 7.3 in general.

Comment: `even Playground temporarily breaks when I have the snippet I mentioned in it` For me too, while editing the code, sometimes the Playground's parser crashes. But it comes back and eventually works. So yes, Xcode 7.3 is fragile, but *it should work*. :p

Comment: @EricD what you're saying makes sense; I have minimal code and frameworks in this project to compare some aspects of different iOS audio frameworks. I'll reboot my machine again and create a whole different project solely for this and see if it reproduces... I'll post back once done. Cheers.

Comment: Excellent idea. I hope you find a solution/explanation to this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Shadowf, are you still having this problem? I encountered the same error message with my code when changing an existing program. I tried several things, including opening a TSI, which is still being processed. Looking on the internet further I stumbled upon this article from bellebethcooper, who said it had to do with the use of AnyObject in dictionaries. I am using dictionaries and solved the problem by first casting the AnyObject to the object I compare it with, or uses it. Can it be a similar problem with your code?

Comment: Thanks @MacUserT - I just read Belle's post (http://blog.bellebethcooper.com/xcode-bug.html) and she did quite a few things that I also tried. The thing is, the problem happens even on a new project with nothing in it but the few lines of code I've described in the question. I've replicated the exact same behaviour on different Macs on bare new projects or even just Playground. I opened a bug with Apple back in March with quite a bit of details, they've never even responded :-(

Comment: @MacUserT if you get any updates at some point, I'd like to know please. I'll also post here if I get any response or idea as to what the cause/solution is. Also, this happens on Xcode 7.3.1 as well (my original post was on 7.3).

Comment: Hi Shadowf, I haven't heard from apple yet, but since I'm casting my AnyObjects the problem has not occurred anymore. Are you using AnyObjects that you're not casting?

Comment: @MacUserT - not at all. I just edited the original question with the exact steps to reproduce the issue. In fact, the moment you put the 3 lines of code in the application (even a brand new project with nothing else but these lines), all hell breaks loose! So there is no dictionary or anything else to speak of.